# Check whether the query is not exist or has a specific value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

For instance we have Example model and we want to do something like below:

```
ex = Example.objects.filter(Q(participant__tries=0) | Q(participant__tries=*THERE IS NO EXAMPLE RECORD*), courses=course)
```

I mean there is no record in the database, not there is and is null. And there is a queryset that never returns any objects.

What should we replace in between two stars?

Appendix:

## My own model

```
class Questions(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, blank=False, db_index=True)
    question_author = models.ForeignKey(Author, blank=False)
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0, editable=False, help_text="<b>***Please Don't change it as much as possible!</b>")
    question_details = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='QuestionsParticipant')
    question_type = models.CharField(choices=question_types, max_length=1, default='1')
    own_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class QuestionsParticipant(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Questions)
    participant = models.ForeignKey(User)
    tries = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    flag_reason = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='')
    success = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

## In my own view:

```
question = Questions.objects.filter(Q(questionsparticipant__tries=0) | Q(questionsparticipant__tries__isnull=True),
                                                Q(questionsparticipant__participant_id=request.user.id)
                                                | Q(questionsparticipant__participant_id__isnull=True),
                                                course=courses, approved=True).order_by("number")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends how your model/schema is set up. You may need to provide additional details.

In many cases, `isnull` will work. For example, `Q(participant__tries__isnull=True)`. See [official docs on `isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#isnull).

Comment: I mean there is no record in the database, not there is and is null. And there is a queryset that never returns any objects.

Comment: (Due to the behavior of the generated `INNER JOIN`.)

Comment: Sorry. Perhaps I am misunderstanding. Can you add the relevant model definitions to the question please?

Comment: I amended it recently.

Comment: Do you mean examples not linked to a participant? Such records would not be included in the queryset, I believe

Comment: I mean if there is no Questionsparticipant record corresponded to Question model